# Calculate CRC with words (16-bit) as a base variable

Tags: c, byte, cpu-word, crc, modbus

Is there a simple CRC algorithm based on a lookup table, but with words entering the algorithm instead of bytes.

For example, this algorithm works with bytes:

```
#include <stdint.h>

const uint16_t wTable_CRC16_Modbus[256] = {
    0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
    0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
    0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
    0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
    0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
    0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
    0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
    0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,

    0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
    0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
    0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
    0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
    0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
    0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
    0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
    0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,

    0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
    0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
    0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
    0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
    0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
    0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
    0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
    0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,

    0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
    0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
    0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
    0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
    0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
    0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
    0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
    0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040
};

uint16_t Modbus_Calculate_CRC16(uint8_t *frame, uint8_t size) {
    // Initialize CRC16 word
    uint16_t crc16 = 0xFFFF;

    // Calculate CRC16 word
    uint16_t ind;
    while(size--) {
        ind = ( crc16 ^ *frame++ ) & 0x00FF;
        crc16 >>= 8;
        crc16 ^= wTable_CRC16_Modbus[ind];
    }

    // Swap low and high bytes
    crc16 = (crc16<<8) | (crc16>>8);

    // Return the CRC16 word with
    // swapped low and high bytes
    return crc16;
}
```

Since I'm always going to send words, using the above algorithm I would need to break each WORD in LSB and MSB and repeat the code in the loop body twice, first for LSB and then for MSB. Instead of doing that, I would like to update CRC in one step, with WORD as the algorithm (loop body) input.

Answer (score 1):

*If and only if* you read words from memory in little-endian order (least significant byte first), then you can read a 16-bit word at a time. You would still need to use the table twice to process the word. The loop would be:

```
    size >>= 1;                     // better have been even!
    uint16_t const *words = frame;  // better be little-endian!
    while (size--) {
        crc16 ^= *words++;
        crc16 = (crc16 >> 8) ^ wTable_CRC16_Modbus[crc16 & 0xff];
        crc16 = (crc16 >> 8) ^ wTable_CRC16_Modbus[crc16 & 0xff];
    }
```

Depending on your processor, you may also need to make sure that `frame` points to an even address. Note that if `size` is odd, this won't process the last byte. If `size` can be and is odd, you can just add the processing of the last byte after the loop.

If you would like a single table lookup per word, then you'll need a much bigger table. The existing table is simply the CRC of the single-byte values 0..255 (where the initial CRC is zero, not `0xffff`). The bigger table would be the same thing, but for the two-byte values 0..65536, with the least significant byte processed first. You can make that table using the existing table:

```
void modbus_bigtable(uint16_t *table) {
    for (uint16_t lo = 0; lo < 256; lo++) {
        uint16_t crclo = wTable_CRC16_Modbus[lo];
        uint16_t crchi = crclo >> 8;
        crclo &= 0xff;
        uint16_t *nxt = table;
        for (uint16_t hi = 0; hi < 256; hi++) {
            *nxt = crchi ^ wTable_CRC16_Modbus[hi ^ crclo];
            nxt += 256;
        }
        table++;
    }
}
```

Then the loop becomes:

```
    size >>= 1;                     // better have been even!
    uint16_t const *words = frame;  // better be little-endian!
    while (size--)
        crc16 = table[crc16 ^ *words++];
```